# Running script on google app engine on deploy

Tags: node.js, gcloud

I'm trying to:

- deploy my nodejs app to google app engine
- have the deploy run a bash script which installs third party dependencies which some of my npm packages require

Now, if I understand correctly, I can't really do this with app engine, I must use compute engine?

Answer (score 0):

Luckily the package is installed by default in Goole App Engine Node.js container.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/runtime

```
build-essential
ca-certificates
curl
python
libkrb5-dev
imagemagick
git
```

I was looking for `imagemagick`.

If custom is required: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/